# Change default category tab selection

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on my university program's website and can't seem to make this change they want. If you visit http://ima-mfa.hunter.cuny.edu/current-courses/ you will see that "All Courses" is activated by default, when I'd like Fall 2014 to be the default. I've tried using jQuery to addClass "active" but it only changes the appearance (gives a red background to the Fall 2014 tab), doesn't update the page with only Fall 2014 courses.

```
<ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
<?php wp_list_categories(array('order' =>'DESC', 'title_li' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'course_semester', 'walker' => new Works_Walker())); ?>
<li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active"><?php _e('All Courses', 'framework'); ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this: `jQuery('a[data-filter=".term39"]').click()`

Comment: no luck :( maybe there is an optimal place to put it though? I stuck it at the footer, and while in that location it will allow me to add the class, the click has no effect

Comment: Hmm, maybe the data-filter attribute is being added via JavaScript then so isn't present at DOM load. You might want to run this code after that has happened, if possible. Have you tried putting it within a `$(document).ready` function?